# Conditional Calculated Field Showing #Error

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to display a Percentage value in a Calculated conditional Files. Below is the Expression

```
=IIF(Sum(Fields!issued.Value)=0,0,Sum(Fields!FrstOutConv.Value)/Sum(Fields!issued.Value))
```

Since I am dividing issued Field I want to ensure the value is not 0. In seen screen grab you can see it works but instead of showing 0 it Shows #Error when issued field is 0
[Image of Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ck1T9.png)   Everything works if I can only show the #Error as 0. As you can see the field Issued has 0 in it not Null or ""
Thanks for any help
Rich V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common mistake...

`IIF` evaluates all parts of the expression every time, so even when your `issued` is 0 and the 2nd part of the `IIF` will never be returned, the `Sum(Fields!FrstOutConv.Value)/Sum(Fields!issued.Value)` part is still evaluated.

You can fix this by using the following.

Instead of

```
=IIF(
    Sum(Fields!issued.Value)=0
    ,0
    ,Sum(Fields!FrstOutConv.Value)/Sum(Fields!issued.Value)
    )
```

use this

```
=IIF(
    Sum(Fields!issued.Value)=0
    ,0
    ,Sum(Fields!FrstOutConv.Value)/IIF(Sum(Fields!issued.Value)=0, 1, Sum(Fields!issued.Value))
    )
```

All this does is force the division to divide by 1 if 'issued `is zero, which is OK because that bit will never be returned if 'issued` is zero.

Comment: Alan, Thanks for the quick response I actually realized that SSRS was evaluating each part of my Equation and yes your fix worked. Thanks Again

Comment: Glad it's working. If this answered your question, please mark the answer as accepted (check mark to the left under the vote up/down buttons), this helps others searching for answers to similar questions.